# Getting all the tasks scheduled in the Quartz.NET scheduler

Tags: quartz.net

How I can get all the tasks that has been scheduled to the Quartz scheduler to display in a web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
string[] groups = myScheduler.JobGroupNames;
for (int i = 0; i < groups.Length; i++)
    {
    string[] names = myScheduler.GetJobNames(groups[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < names.Length; j++)
        {
        // groups[i]
        // names[j]
        }
    }
```